# Scala.js - How to convert Array[Byte] to Blob?

Tags: scala.js

DOM API requires `Blob` but all I have is `Array[Byte]`. How can I do the conversion?

```scala
import org.scalajs.dom.Blob

def toBlob(input: Array[Byte]): Blob = {
  // code in question
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me (not sure about `js.Array` though).

```scala
import org.scalajs.dom.Blob
import scala.scalajs.js
import scalajs.js.typedarray.AB2TA

def toBlob(input: Array[Byte]): Blob = {
  new Blob(js.Array(input.toTypedArray))
}
```

Comment: The `js.Array` wrapper should not be required. `new Blob(input.toTypedArray)` should work as well.

Comment: @sjrd Found: scala.scalajs.js.typedarray.Int8Array Required: scala.scalajs.js.Iterable[org.scalajs².dom.BlobPart]

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Comment: Added some more info